# Access php arrays within arrays

Tags: php

I am trying to access arrays within arrays but don't know how so plz help me.

The values  $row[0],$row[1],....  are representing columns of database and I am inserting all of it in $rows[] array.

Now I want to access these values and don't know how.So please help me.

```
        while($row=mysql_fetch_array(self::$results))
        {
            $rows[] = array ('CompanyID' => $row[0],
                             'CompanyName' => $row[1], 
                             'CompanySlogan' => $row[2], 
                             'CompanyDescription' => $row[3], 
                             'CompanyRating' => $row[4],
                             'CompanyDpPath'  => $row[5],
                             'CompanyOtherInfo' => $row[6],
                             'CompanyFollowers' => $row[7]);
        }
```

The data is being hold in the following manner

```
Array ( [0] => Array ( [CompanyID] => 3 [CompanyName] => s [CompanySlogan] => s [CompanyDescription] => and so on.
```

Comment: before the while loop add an variable wich equals an empty array to dump those subarrays in it. $buffer = array(); . And in the while loop use that array {

$buffer[] = array(....

}

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As simple as

```
$rows[0]['CompanyID']
```

Comment: thnx for the answer but what if I want only single value because I've two records of companyId and it is returning me both of them.like if companyid is 2 it is giving me 22 as answer and I want single 2 at a time

Comment: @Mj1992 Then it is really 22. The data doesn't lie.

Comment: @Mj1992: `var_dump($rows);` - this function helps you to become a real programmer: the guy who doesn't guess but knows for sure

Comment: `Array ( [0] => Array ( [CompanyID] => 3 [CompanyName] => s )) Array ( [0] => Array ( [CompanyID] => 3 [CompanyName] => s ))` it is showing data in the following manner you can see that companyID is appearing multiple times and I want to access the first one and second one differently

Comment: @Mj1992: it is not `var_dump` for `$rows`. It is `var_dump` for some another variable (or you've shown us another code)

Comment: Sry I didn't understand what you said.

Comment: @Mj1992: I asked for `var_dump($rows);`. And you've shown something other. Have you read php documentation about how to work with arrays? http://nz.php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php

Comment: thnx understand what you said.`var_dump` is very helpful.